# Array as PathParam or QueryString in Restful web services

Tags: arrays, rest

I need to send integer, string array as pathparam or query string to get the values from the database. The use case is that i have the array of user ids and i need to send it as parameter so it can return the data w.r.t that users only. I am using jboss RestEasy API but not able to find how to pass arrays as pathparam or query string.

Kindly let me know how to do this?

Thanks in advance 
Shuja

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried for Passing array but i have checked with List<...>

```
import java.util.List;
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public String getCustomers(
    @QueryParam("start") int start,
    @QueryParam("size") int size,
    @QueryParam("orderBy") List<String> orderBy) {
...
}
}
```

hope that you get hint form this.